# VS Load Test - why am I seeing more requests in results to recorded

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Newbie to Visual Studio load testing
When I record a web performance test I get a list of requests, when I run this test some of the 'requests' expand to show more. 
Q: why can I not see all these requests in the recorded list?
If I run the same actions with a tool like LoadUIWeb I see all these requests in the recording, none hidden.
I want to be able to test the website with and without calls to external sites like google-analytics, etc.

I found from googling that it appears that the only way around this is to write a plugin.

I'm surprised that I'd have to do this as other tools will show all requests on the recorded script. I want to ensure that there isn't something I'm missing...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "expanded request" or "child requests" are actually dependent requests. If your site has dependencies to other resources (e.g. images, scripts, css files, etc...) it will result on additional HTTP requests made to obtain these resources (assuming they are not cached locally). VS will simulate this behavior by analyzing the body and issuing dependent requests.

The reason they are not recorded is because they may change.

The following question provides very useful information about the behavior of dependent requests: [How can I turn off request caching in a Visual Studio load test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679470/how-can-i-turn-off-request-caching-in-a-visual-studio-load-test)